# Scrolling with shift-control-pageup in gnome-terminal

Tags: terminal, tmux, gnome-terminal

Is it possible to configure `tmux` (inside `gnome-terminal`) so that the key combinations <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Page Down</kbd> can be used to scroll up and down in the terminal's history?

Answer (score 2):

There are two "problems" with these shortcut keys.

The first is: these are handled by gnome-terminal itself by default; they shuffle the order of the tabs. You need to disable this behavior in Prefs -> Shortcuts.

The second is: after this, these are still handled by gnome-terminal the way <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> (without <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>) is handled; that is, scroll in the history buffer. Newest versions of gnome-terminal and vte actually emit some escape sequence if you're on the so-called alternate screen (which doesn't have a scrollback), and luckily tmux switches to this.

So far, you should disable the shortcuts as mentioned above, and (without running tmux) switch to the alternate screen and test if the keys indeed emit something. Execute

```
echo -ne '\e[?47h'
cat
```

and press these keys. You need to see `^[[5;6~` and `^[[6;6~` appearing. If they don't, you might have an old gnome-terminal and vte, and upgrading should help.

The next step is configuring tmux to recognize these. I'm not familiar with that, but I'm quite certain it's easily doable.